# Rich swing radiobutton

Tags: java, swing, widget, jradiobutton

Developing a desktop application based on Java + Swing I faced the problem of creating a radio button which instead of text next to it, should have and image or, say, another widget like a spinner.

Clicking on the image or the spinner should select also the corresponding radioButton.

Is it possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, the JRadioButton with icon given for constructor doesn't seem to work; it replaces the "native radio button icon" with given icon. I think to original asked wanted for radio button with icon in addition to the "radio button icon".

There has been some debate on the behaviour at Sun bug database with [Bug #4177248](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=9219c071516802ffffffffb5fbc844da63293?bug_id=4177248) but no changes have been made.

Instead, one could try [JRadioButtonMenuItem](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButtonMenuItem.html), even though there will probably be some non-wanted behaviour with that?

Short evaluation for both JRadioButton and JRadioButtonMenuItem:

```
public class IconRadioButtonEval {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        // Use some arbitrary working URL to an icon
        URL url =
                new URL(
                        "http://mikeo.co.uk/demo/sqlspatial/Images/RSS_Icon.png");
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(icon);
        panel.add(new JLabel("RadioButton with icon:"));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(new JLabel("RadioButtonMenuItem with icon:"));
        panel.add(new JRadioButtonMenuItem(icon));

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Justin's suggestion for another component next to JRadioButton with empty string should probably work well in most cases.

Comment: your solution help me to add text and icon to the radioButton, and I want to ask you about your expression _"even though there will probably be some non-wanted behaviour with that?"_ what kind of _non-wanted behaviour_ Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a constructor for `JRadioButton` that takes an `Icon`.  You can use that to make it have an icon next to it.

> [**`JRadioButton(Icon icon)`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html)
>
> -- Creates an initially unselected radio button with the specified image but no text.

Otherwise, it is fairly easy to make the `JRadioButton`s text empty, and place another component next to it.  Then you will need to add a Listener to that component, so that the `JRadioButton` gets clicked if the other component gets clicked.

Comment: Have you tried that constructor? It seems to replace the original radio button image instead of adding the icon next to it (see the evaluation in another answer) (-1). Approach with another component would probably work well (+1)